# why can't getting value from wordpress database nextgen gallery in selection tag dropdown

Tags: database, wordpress, foreach, selection

Hy all I have this code this is printing the array in the result but not getting value in the selectin dropdown I want to get the nextgen gallery names from the database! Tell me where I am wrong

```
<select>
<?php
foreach($gallerylist as $galleryrow) {?>
<?php echo $galleryrow; ?>
<option value="<?php echo $galleryrow; ?>"><?php echo $galleryrow; ?></option>
<?php}
?>
</select> 
global $wpdb;
$gallerydefine= $wpdb->prefix."ngg_gallery";
$query="SELECT * FROM $gallerydefine";
$gallerylist = $wpdb->get_results($query);
```

Comment: please can you tell me the right way??

Comment: What do you mean? It's not for a comment, check my answer, please.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is out of order. Change it to:

```
<?php
global $wpdb;
$gallerydefine = $wpdb->prefix."ngg_gallery";
$query="SELECT * FROM {$gallerydefine}";
$gallerylist = $wpdb->get_results($query);
?>
<select>
<?php
foreach($gallerylist as $galleryrow) {?>

<option value="<?php echo $galleryrow->gid; ?>"><?php echo $galleryrow->name; ?></option>
<?php}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: No kgreene it's not about the order i have changed that but problem is still!

Comment: dear i have changed this according to your given code can you please check when i print result it's showing this!                                                                                                         Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [gid] => 1 [name] => taekwondo [slug] => Taekwondo [path] => wp-content/gallery/taekwondo/ [title] => Taekwondo [galdesc] => Taekwono Event Photos [pageid] => 2031 [previewpic] => 1 [author] => 1 [extras_post_id] => 525 ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [gid] => 2 [name] => muay-thai-event [slug] =>      i just upload half!

Comment: I edited again  using the fields you showed. That should work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try to read your code as a book:

1. First, you're trying to print a list of galleries (which you don't have, it's an undefined variable) as a selectbox:

   ```
   <select>
   <?php
   foreach($gallerylist as $galleryrow) { ?>
       <?php echo $galleryrow; ?>
       <option value="<?php echo $galleryrow; ?>"><?php echo $galleryrow; ?></option>
   <?php } ?>
   </select>
   ```
2. After that, you're loading the list of galleries from the database, but you're not using it for anything, you just load it and then the script ends:

   ```
   global $wpdb;
   $gallerydefine= $wpdb->prefix."ngg_gallery";
   $query="SELECT * FROM $gallerydefine";
   $gallerylist = $wpdb->get_results($query);
   ```

Obviously, it doesn't make any sense. It's like having a lunch where you first "eat it" (even though you don't have it) and then you go buy ingredients, cook it and go sleep without actually eating it.

Just think about what you're doing it put everything in the right order.

#### Important notes

1. **enable [reporting](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.error-reporting) and [displaying](https://www.php.net/manual/en/errorfunc.configuration.php#ini.display-errors) of all errors including warnings and notices** on your local development environment. If you would have it enabled, you know immediately you're doing something wrong: it would tell you you're using an undefined variable `$gallerylist` inside the `foreach` loop.
2. Also, it's a good idea to **check if there hasn't been any database error** right after you make a database query.
3. Always **check what HTML code is your script generating**. You may see just a blank web page but there may be a lot of HTML code behind that. You're for example printing text between HTML tags `<select>` and `<option>` which is not valid.
4. And **use a debugger** and go through your script step by step. You'll understand in what order the statements are being executed, what values variables contain in a particular point in the time, etc.